# footer text cant get to move

Tags: css, text, footer, move

Please keep in mind that I am still learning HTML/CSS.

I have been working on a website for a client and have reached the point of being finished, however the footer is driving me insane!

I need two columns of text to follow the flow of the website, but no matter what I try the left column is stuck to the very end of the page and I cant move it to the center where the other column currently sits.

The website is http://www.eplsdesign.com/Grow/index.php

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Hi now you **write** to in **your html** `<div id="wrapper">` now it's change into `<div class="wrapper">`

Now just now **replace** to this

```
<div id="footer">
<div id="wrapper">
```

**into this**

```
<div id="footer">
<div class="wrapper">
```